# E-Commerce product search: whitespace or not?

Tags: solr, lucene, search-engine, information-retrieval

I am building a product search engine for an e-commerce website.

Documents come from heterogeneous sources so, for now, I cannot fix them.

I have some document descriptions like these:

```
GOPRO CAMERA 32
GOPRO CAMERA 35
```

Some others like these:

```
GO-PRO BATTERY 1000
GO-PRO BATTERY 2000
```

and finally others like these:

```
GO PRO CASE SLIM BLUE
GO PRO CASE SLIM RED
GO PRO CASE SLIM GREEN
```

My field type for description field is "text_it":

```
<fieldType name="text_it" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer type="index">
                <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
                <filter class="solr.ElisionFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" articles="lang/contractions_it.txt"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_it.txt" format="snowball" />
                <filter class="solr.ItalianLightStemFilterFactory"/>
            </analyzer>
            <analyzer type="query">
                <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
                <filter class="solr.ElisionFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" articles="lang/contractions_it.txt"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_it.txt" format="snowball" />
                <filter class="solr.ItalianLightStemFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>x
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
```

Obviously, when I submit a query like **GO PRO** I find results from each of the three groups listed above.

When instead I search **GOPRO** I find results from just the first two groups. I know from the analysis form that the reason for that is the tokens indexed are:

GOPRO => gopro
GO-PRO => gopro, go, pro
GO PRO => go, pro

What do you suggest me for having the **gopro** query (without whitespace) matching the GO PRO product (with whitespace), too?

**UPDATE**

I tried adding this to my query analyzer, after *LowerCaseFilter*:

```
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="50" side="front" />
```

... and it works, for my use case: query "gopro" generates g,go,gop,gopr,gopro tokens and here it is. Ok, but now all other query results are ruined! 
First result for query "essential" is "dvd player es-124", because of "es" token being generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will get anywhere interesting with a generic tokenizer that applies to all the words in your documents - whichever solution you try, you will run into the type of problems you describe, because the "special" tokenization will apply to everything (not just the words you're interested in like gopro in your case), which will lead to spurious matches.

Instead, I would say you need to look at your brands individually, and make a list of all their different spellings, for example: gopro, go pro. Then use a SynonymFilterFactory - the official documentation gives a clear and relevant example of how to do it:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory

Comment: what about making "shingles"?
"go pro camera" => "gopro", "procamera" + original ?

Comment: same issue; you would want to do that only for a very specific list of words (the brand names - you wouldn't want a generic tokenizer that would also  shingle "slow motion camera" for example) so you have to go to a hand-curated list of synonyms. I think for your example you'll need two lines in the synonym list, one for gopro, and one for gopro camera, if you need to identify the search procamera.

Comment: What did you end up doing? Please accept the answer if it was useful :)

Comment: Indeed it is, but I ended up trying shingles token filter